# How to cluster search engine keywords?

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, keyword

From Google Analytics I have a (long) list of keywords that people used in search engines to find my website. I want to find the 'core keywords', hypothetical example:

```
java online training
learning java
scala training
training for java
online training java
learn scala programming
```

The ideal result would be: 'java', 'online training', 'training', 'scala' and 'learn'.

The difficulty seems to be detecting complete phrases, ignoring common words (for) and handling variations (learn-learning).

*Is there a library that can do that (preferably for JVM)? Or is there a suitable algorithm I can implement myself?*

Comment: I think you need to spend more time specifying your requirements.  Even in your limited example I don't know why you don't consider "programming" to be "core".

Comment: What if you would use googles number of results for finding good keywords? Scala would have less results than for -> better word. You could do a search for all possible phrases and record number of results for each phrase, then find a range where good phrases exists. (That was just a quick thought, so I'm not putting it as an answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a term or keyword extraction problem. I did a search and it turned up [Kea](http://current.com/1vi9m4c), which looks to be very much what you want.

You can implement a naive solution by the following algorithm:

- generate a list of ngrams in the document with the phrase length that you want (chose an arbitrary phrase length limit, like 3 or 4)
- put the ngram into a [Multiset](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html)
- iterate over the entries of the multiset in the order of their degree or count, perhaps with an arbitrary cutoff

Like you said, this will have a problem with stopwords. You can do something simple like have a dictionary of stopwords, or you can do something like [Term Frequency-Inverse Document Frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) which can help you automatically recognize very frequent terms. KEA will do this for you, it might be best to look into that first.

Hope that helps!